# Initialize dataPicker with start value that is not the first value of the array that set the dataPicker values

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, datapicker

I initialized the dataPicker with values from array. With runtime the dataPicker is first shown the value of the first value of the array (`array[0]`) and I want that the first value will be the the value for the `array[4]`, for example. How should I do that????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading select the row you want...

```
int theRowIWant = 4;
[picker selectRow:theRowIWant inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectRow%3ainComponent%3aanimated%3a)